# Rejecting inputs that include WWW. in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to block inputs of domains without www. in regex Bash.

Was using :  \b(?:(?!www.)\w)+\b

Update:

Was able to resolve this issue by using the suggested expression.

Successfully Implemented As

```
while [[ ! $domain =~ www.*[.]([^\s]+) ]]; do

            echo "Enter domain without www."                           
            read domain
            echo
    done
```

Comment: What expressions have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Are you using `grep`, or something else for the regex?

Comment: use `grep -P` for perl regex in the newer versions of GNU grep it works fine with lookaheads etc

Comment: Why not check if the first three characters of the input is `www`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determinate domains with "www." and then block them

With http/https:

```
 http[s]*:\/\/www.*[.]([^\s]+)
```

without http/https:

```
www.*[.]([^\s]+)
```